# How can we use C# without ASP.NET with a JS framework for developing Single Page Applications?

Tags: c#, api, single-page-application

I am looking for a way to use `HTML`, `CSS`, `JS Framework like Angular or Vue` in the front page and use `C#` without `ASP.NET` in the backend to develop Single Page Applications. Is there any possible way to do it? I mean can we use `C#` without `ASP.NET` in the backend as an `API` and develop Single Page APPS?

I googled it a lot but did not find any helpful resources so I came here to get help of the stackoverflow experience.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: May I ask what your use case is? If you want to host an API on the backend you will need some form of a web server. ASP.NET is a popular choice, there are also other options. But in general, you wouldn't write low level C# code yourself to handle this kind of situations.

Comment: @WouterdeKort : I would like to use C# in the backend for API that will handle http requests just like we can use Laravel for backend and Vue for front end.

Comment: Based on what you've described, [ASP.NET Web API](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/apps/aspnet/apis) sounds to be what you're looking for. If you don't like ASP.NET, it'd help if you give specific reasons *why* you don't like it. Otherwise, how is anyone to provide an effective alternative?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, ASP.NET is an entirely optional part of a .NET web application.

Depending on how you want to host it, you can just let your code work in an Owin middleware, an IIS module or handler or a plain old HttpListener, and so on, causing "raw" HTTP requests to end up in your code.

You can then mix and match features from ASP.NET or third-party libraries such as routing, security, content negotiation (serialization), bundling and minification and effectively you'll be creating a Frankenstein monster that won't work as well as ASP.NET and that others can barely maintain.

At least one such framework already exists and is called "Nancy", and has all the drawbacks mentioned above, in addition to a barely maintained and poorly debuggable cousin of Razor.

So the answer is "yes, but why?".

Comment: Because I do not like ASP.NET so I want to use C# as the backend just like we can use Laravel as the api and vue is the front end.

Comment: Why don't you like ASP.NET? Anyhow see my answer for alternatives. The second paragraph should get you started.